# Using Rcpp to create boxplots from a data frame

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have a data set that contains 11 variables and 4177 observations. I am trying to create rcpp functions to determine the five number summary (min, max, median, first quantile, third quantile) in r. I created three functions that work when I use the argument data$x (x being a variable). However, i need to iterate over all of my data set to create 11 boxplots using rcpp and the functions i have created for the five number summary. Here is my code for the three functions:

```
cppFunction('double mincpp(std::vector<double> data) {
  double mincpp = data.at(0);
  for (unsigned int i = 1; i < data.size(); i++) {
    if (data.at(i) < mincpp) {
      mincpp = data.at(i);
    }
  }
  return mincpp;
}')

cppFunction('double maxcpp(std::vector<double> data) {
  double maxcpp = data.at(0);
  for (unsigned int i = 1; i < data.size(); i++) {
    if (data.at(i) > maxcpp) {
      maxcpp = data.at(i);
    }
  }
  return maxcpp;
}')

cppFunction('double medcpp(Rcpp::NumericVector data){
  std::size_t size = data.size();
  std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
  if (size  % 2 == 0) return (data[size / 2 - 1] + data[size / 2]) / 2.0;
  return data[size / 2];
}')
```

I am unsure of how to call these functions within a loop to iterate over my variables to create boxplots as an output. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to use Rcpp for this? Your data is not very large and these types of summaries are very efficiently done in R itself. If you are using standard R base graphics then you won't see any speed up creating those in Rcpp.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @Madison, and to the world of Rcpp.  As you have found `cppFunction()`, keep reading the documentation, especially on `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` as you want a package for this.  But as MrFlick asutely notes, you may be going about this the wrong way and you will likely not beat base R (which uses compiled code for time-critical ops).